# Debug buttons moved to left side in visual studio while Debugging

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Anyone knows how to fix this problem? When i start debug these buttons moved to the left side and it's doesn't convenient for me, also i didn't change anything [image: debug tools]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on these dots and move that section wherever you want.

[image: How to rearrange header options in Visual Studio.]

Comment: @Taifunov no problem, you can accept answer to close this topic.